# Laravel validator ignore unique rule on update model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to validate an unique e-mail on 2 tables.

Something like:

*Foo* model

```
$rules = [ email: 'required|unique:foo|unique:bar' ];
```

*Bar* model

```
$rules = [ email: 'required|unique:bar|unique:foo' ];
```

Above rules works fine **on creating** the models. The problem is when i need to update it.

**On updating** Laravel Validator ignore the unique rules. For example, if set:

*Bar* || *Foo* model

```
$rules = [ email: 'required|unique:WHATEVER|unique:WHATEVER' ];
```

When save i don't have exceptions or errors and the unique validations rule works only on the table of model. (don't matter if table name is wrong)

> To make sure, the email columns has *unique* index on database

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: looking at `composer.json`: `"branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "5.0-dev"
        }`